# What is the best practice to prevent an instance from init() in a Singleton class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I learned from Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C that a singleton can be created like this:

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
}
```

But as I learned, we should also prevent an instance created from the constructor. Creating an instance of the class Singleton outside the class  scope, like the statement below, should be prevented:

```
let inst = Singleton()
```

So, could I do just like this:

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    private init() {}
}
```

Or, is there any better practice?

Comment: @waterlee23 Actually, it can. As Jacob Joz says, it results in a compile time error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way that you have suggested is the way that I always implemented it.

```
public class Singleton
{
    static public let sharedInstance = Singleton();

    private init()
    {

    }
}
```

It's the cleanest solution for a Singleton pattern that I've ever found. Now that in Swift 2 you can specify accessibility it does actually prevent you from calling something like:

```
var mySingleton = Singleton();
```

Doing so results in a compile time error:

```
'Singleton' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
```

Comment: Making the `init()` `private` does not appear prevent you from calling `Singleton()` when I tested it in a Playground.

Answer (score 1):

```
private let singletonInstance = Singleton()

final class Singleton: NSObject {
    static func getInstance() -> Singleton {
        return singletonInstance
    }
}
```

Try that. Nothing is wrong in using global object here, it is created lazily (on first call).